# Word Counter with hyphen

Tags: java

I have this Question:
You will need to make some assumptions about words. Perhaps the simplest assumption is that a word is a sequence of alpha-­‐numeric characters which may or may not contain a hyphen. Using his definition we can easily count words because they will be terminated by the occurrence of a space character.

This is my code, can you please help me to develop my code with consideration of the Question above ?

```
public void counting()
{
   while (file.hasNextLine()) // to count lines
   {
     Clines++;
     Scanner line = new Scanner (file.nextLine());

    while (line.hasNext()) // to conunt words
    {
        Cwords++;
        String word = line.next();

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
         Cchars++;
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not here to do your homework for you

Comment: Sure, what help do you need? It's unclear what your question is.

Comment: If I have word which is divided into two words because of the hyphen like "comme_ enter"  although it is one word. How can I count them as one word ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the words of the line you should do this:

```
public void counting()
{
   int wordCount = 0;
   while (file.hasNextLine()) // to count lines
   {
     Clines++;
     Scanner line = new Scanner (file.nextLine());
     wordCount += line.split(" ").length;  
   }
}
```

Comment: But what if I have word which is divided into two words because of the hyphen like "comme_ enter" although it is one word. How can I count them as one word ?

Comment: A word that contains a hyphen is considered one word, not two.

Comment: With this code, the words are joined by a hyphen counted as one word. But if what you want is a function that counts the words you should declare as follows `public int counting()` and return the variable wordCount `return wordCount;` after the while loop. I hope I have solved your question, if so please vote my answer positively.